# Swift UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I'm very new here and I have nowhere else to ask this so I apologize for my format in this question.

So I accidentally edited my UITableView on the Main.Storyboard (I accidentally removed my 1 and only protoype Cell) and when I tried to put back the prototype cell and reconnecting my UITableViewCell variable, it is giving me this error now:

"The dropDownCurrCell outlet from the SettingsViewController to the UITableViewCell is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content."

I have this code

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listCurrencies.count
}
//listing the cell for the supported currencies
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let listCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "supportedCurrencies", for: indexPath)
    
    listCell.textLabel!.text = String( listCurrencies[indexPath.row].currName)
    
    return listCell
}
```

and

```
@IBOutlet var dropDownCurr: UITableView!{
    didSet {
        dropDownCurr.dataSource = self
        dropDownCurr.delegate = self
        }
}

@IBOutlet weak var dropDownCurrCell: UITableViewCell!
```

What do you guys happened? I just started trying to learn Swift.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJUdo.png)

Comment: You don't connect table cell instances to an outlet in your view controller.  Delete the `dropDownCurrCell` outlet.  Cells have a cell identifier and you use that in `cellForRow(at:)` to create cell instances

Comment: both on the .swift and storyboard?

Comment: You keep the prototype cell in your storyboard, but you don't create any outlets from it to your view controller.  If you have a `UITableViewCell` subclass for that prototype cell then you link the contents of your cell (labels, text field etc) to outlets in the cell subclass

Comment: I've deleted the outlets for the prototype cell in the view controller and kept the prototype cell on my storyboard, but I still have the same error. I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding this.

Comment: It is telling you that you are trying to link (or have linked) an item in your prototype cell (or the cell itself) to an outlet in your view controller class.

Comment: It's fixed! thank you very much for the help

Comment: How do I mark your answer as the correct answer? or +rep your profile

Comment: These are just comments. I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you are trying to link (or have linked) an item in your prototype cell (or the cell itself) to an outlet in your view controller class.

You don't connect table cell instances to an outlet in your view controller since you will have multiple cells (repeating content) and only one view controller instance. Cells have a cell identifier and you use that in `cellForRow(at:)` to create cell instance.

Delete the `dropDownCurrCell` outlet and any links from the prototype cell in the storyboard to the view controller.

If you have a `UITableViewCell` subclass for the prototype cell then you link the contents of your cell (labels, text fields etc) to `@IBOutlet`s in the cell subclass